# where is main Java class in Jar specified

Tags: java

I've downloaded JAR archive [from here](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). I want to know which class is the main. I checked Manifest file for main class specification `Main-Class: com.some.className` but it's not there. Where else could the main class be specified?

Comment: What makes you think there is a `main` method there at all? As far as I can see okhttp is a library, not a program.

Comment: I'm just starting with Java so I don't know if it's possible to not specify it. If it's not specified then how is it determined what class to start running with when executing `.jar` file? Command line options?

Comment: I think I get it. Since it's a library and not an application it is not launched as a separate application so it doesn't need main class. Its classes are used as a dependency for other classes. Could that be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OkHttp is meant to be used as a library. One of the easiest ways to build java programs that need library dependencies is to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). In the absence of Maven or other tools you can get the program running by copying the jar to a folder. You will also need to download [okio](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/squareup/okio/okio/1.0.1/okio-1.0.1.jar).

To try the library out, create a java file in the same folder that contains the 2 jars and call this file GetExample.java . Paste the example source from the OkHttp [site](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/square/okhttp/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/guide/GetExample.java).

To compile the program, open a terminal/command prompt window and go to the location where you have GetExample.java and the jar files. Run the command:

> javac -cp okhttp-2.1.0.jar GetExample.java

This should compile the file and create GetExample.class for you.

To run the program use the command:

> java -cp okhttp-2.1.0.jar:okio-1.0.1.jar:. GetExample

or, if you are using windows (replace : with ;):

> java -cp okhttp-2.1.0.jar;okio-1.0.1.jar;. GetExample

You should see the content of a [README.md](https://raw.github.com/square/okhttp/master/README.md) file.

I hope this helps.